# React Fetch Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm getting `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`in my React app - while that typically means that I'm searching for the incorrect data type (object vs. array, for instance), I'm unable to console.log my API URL, which makes me think something else is wrong.

Here's my code, everything exists in my App.js file so it's not an issue with calling other components or anything:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const APIURL = `https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?`;
const citySearch = `by_state=new_york`;

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      breweries: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(APIURL + citySearch)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            breweries: result.breweries
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, breweries } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
    return (
          <ul>
            {breweries.map(brewery => (
              <li key={brewery.id}>
              {brewery.name} {brewery.city}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
     );
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here's the data I'm trying to get - if I copy and paste my APIURL into my browser, I get the data - so I'm not sure where `undefined` is coming from:

```
[{"id":4581,"name":"Adirondack Toboggan Company Microbrewery","brewery_type":"micro","street":"202A W Main St","city":"Gouverneur","state":"New York","postal_code":"13642-1334","country":"United States","longitude":"-75.4748923846074","latitude":"44.3323731052224","phone":"3157716313","website_url":"http://www.adktoboggan.net","updated_at":"2018-08-24T15:37:58.899Z","tag_list":[]}, (AND SO ON)...
```

As I've just started this app, I'm just trying to make sure my fetch request works so I can build out components.

Am I getting `undefined` because of how I'm searching for the data (which seems to be the solution to other questions like mine) or is something else going on that prevents me from even logging my `APIURL` const?

Comment: you dont have breweries field in your api so it is normal to take undefined error!

Comment: So in my setState should I just change `breweries: result.breweries` to just `breweries: result`?

Comment: That worked, thank you!